# TypeError: undefined is not an object on Paw app

Tags: paw-app

I installed some new plugin on Paw app (Postman 1 and 2 export, Swagger 2). And since I have this error when I try to make a new export. I tried to uninstall and reinstall only one plugin, and I still have this error.

But before I install some new plugin, I made some export without error.

This is the error I get when I attempt to make an export:

**Export Failed**

```js
JavaScript Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ds.length') ({
    column = 20;
    line = 2277;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the very late follow up. We've been able to reproduce this issue, and release a fix last week.

Please update your Paw extensions by going to the **Paw menu > Extensions > Check for Extensions Updates**…
This will trigger the updating of all your installed extensions. Then, please try again to export your project, it should be working correctly.